# SSRS String to Date conversion (mmddyyyy)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

I have a String field in a Dataset in (mmddyyyy) format.

I am trying to convert it into a Date field in SSRS.

I already tried using the below command but I am getting error.

```vb
CDate(Fields!LocalTXNDate.Value)
```

Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: Why isn't your column a date and time data type in the first place?

Comment: I have a string field in database itself and our requirement is to convert it into Date in SSRS

Comment: Why is the "requirement" to do it in SSRS? Why not fix the design in the database, string based data types are a **terrible** data type for date and time values; `'10072022'` is **before** `'12171927'`.

Comment: Also why tag SSRS 2008 and 2005? Which are you *really* using? *Both* are also *completely* unsupported (for over 3 and 6 years respectively). It is *long* past time you got your upgrade paths finalised and implemented.

Comment: Getting limited tags for SSRS in the suggestion that's why using SSRS 2008,2005.

Right now we are using SSRS 2019

Comment: The you should tag [[tag:ssrs-2019]], not 2 completely different (and completely) unsupported versions.

Comment: Any suggestion or idea do you think by how we can handle this

Comment: Yes, fix your design; change the data type of the column to a `date` (which will also require fixing of your data first, as `MMddyyyy` isn't a recognised format in SQL Server in any language or [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles)). Then the value can be passed to SSRS as the correct data type to start with.

Comment: All these comments about fix your design/data type. Sometimes this is NOT an option. The data comes in from somewhere else you have no control over, and someone wants a report and wants it formatted nicely.

Answer (score 3):

While Larnu is correct, the way to do it is to correct the database, sometimes we lowly report makers have no say in making these changes - much less getting a DBA to do it in a reasonable amount of time.

If you can't change the data to be correct, the easiest way to convert and use the field as a date is to add a Calculated Field to the Dataset. Open the dataset properties, click on the Fields tab, Add a Calculated field.
[image]

For the Expression, use string functions to parse the field into a generic date format and then CDATE to convert to a date type. Then use the new field for dates. You could also use this in your text box if it's not being reused but it's easier to manipulate the Calculated field.

```
=CDATE(
    RIGHT(Fields!LocalTXNDate.Value, 4) & "-" & 
    LEFT(Fields!LocalTXNDate.Value, 2) & "-" & 
    MID(Fields!LocalTXNDate.Value, 3, 2)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't SSRS but your data, and that you are using a string based data type to store the data. You need to fix the problem at the source, not at the report level.

The string format you have chosen, `MMddyyyy` isn't a format that is recognised by default in any of the languages in SQL Server, nor if you explicitly use `SET DATEFORMAT`, nor does it appear as a [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles). `SET DATEFORMAT MDY; SELECT CONVERT(date,'11172022');` will fail. Therefore you'll need to first do some string manipulation on the data first to be an unambiguous format (`yyyyMMdd`):

```sql
UPDATE YT
SET YourDateColumn = CONVERT(varchar(8),V.DateValue,112)
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(date,CONCAT(RIGHT(YT.YourDateColumn,4),LEFT(YT.YourDateColumn,4)))))V(DateValue);
```

For any bad values you have, such as `'17112022'` this will `UPDATE` the value to `NULL`; as such you may want to create a new column for the new value, or perhaps a new column to store the value of dates that couldn't be converted.

After you've changed the value to an unambiguous format, then you can `ALTER` the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLe dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourDateColumn date NULL;
```

Note that if you have any constraints, you will need to `DROP` those first, and then re`CREATE` them afterwards.

Now that the data type of the column is correct, you need not do anything in SSRS, as the data type is correct.